# What do these single quotes do at the beginning of line 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, join, syntax

I found the following code in some random website explaining concatenating:

```
data_numb = input("Input Data, then press enter: ")
numb = ''.join(list(filter(str.isdigit, data_numb)))
print('(' + numb[:3] + ') ' + numb[3:6] + '-' + numb[6:])
```

and I was wondering what the single quotes do in the

```
numb = ''.join(
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) in the documentation. In this case you have an empty string.

Comment: They tell `join` the character with which to join a sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`join(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) is a method from the `str` class.

> Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in iterable.
>   A TypeError will be raised if there are any non-string values in
>   iterable, including bytes objects. The separator between elements is
>   the string providing this method.

`''.join(("Hello", "World"))` will return `'HelloWorld'`.

`';'.join(("Hello", "World", "how", "are", "you"))` will return `'Hello;World;how;are;you'`.

`join` is very helpful if you need to add a delimiter between each element from a list (or any iterable) of strings.

It looks like nothing but if you do not use `join`, this kind of operation is often ugly to implement because of edge effects:

For a list or tuple of strings :

```
def join(list_strings, delimiter):
    str_result = ''
    for e in list_strings[:-1]:
        str_result += e + delimiter

    if list_strings:
        str_result += list_strings[-1]

    return str_result
```

For any iterable :

```
def join(iterable, delimiter):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    str_result = ''
    try: 
        str_result += next(iterator)
        while True:
            str_result += delimiter + next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        return str_result
```

Because `join` works on any iterable, you don't need to create a list from the filter result.

```
numb = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, data_numb))
```

works as well

Answer (score 0):

Join method is used to concatenate a string with any iterable object. In this example, the first string is an empty string, also represented by two single quotes, `''` (don't confuse the single quotes with a single double quote).

The `join()` method of a string object concatenates it with another iterable provided. So, if the first string is an empty string, the resultant string is the concatenated output of the elements in the iterable.

**What is its use:**

1. It can be used to concatenate a list of strings. For example:

   ```
   a = ['foo', 'bar']
   b = ''.join(a)
   print(b) # foobar
   ```
2. It can be used to concatenate strings. (Since a string is an iterable, as well)

   ```
   a = "foobar"
   b = ''.join(a)
   print(b) # foobar
   ```

You can think of more use cases, but this is just a gist of it. You can also refer to the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

Comment: Can someone fix the code marking? I cannot get it (the four spaces) to work. Maybe I am using it inside a list? Currently I have marked the codeblocks using backticks (`).

Comment: You shouldn't use backticks for multi-line blocks of code. Since the list already puts 4 spaces of indentation into the editor, you need to indent your lines of code an extra 4 spaces (making 8 in total)

Comment: You're right. I just used it as a work around. I forgot that the list has to be also given 4 spaces. :P Thanks, though. :D